# Sum from LINQ query

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

Cannot get this to work. Want to get the sum of all the amounts int the database from the following LINQ statement:

```
        Dim currentPaid = From a In db.Payments
                          Where a.ForJob = id
                          Select a.Amount

        Dim totalPaid As Double = currentPaid.Sum()
```

As it underlines the second statment and says:
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Sum' accepts this number of attributes.

Comment: What type is `currentPaid`? Are you sure that the error message is `...number of attributes` instead of `number of arguments`?

Comment: currentPaid is the LINQ query above? Not sure if I should just do the sum in the LINQ statement

Comment: What type is `currentPaid`, is it an `IEnumerable(Of String)`,`IEnumerable(Of Double)` or what else? Try to declare it with the type and you might see a compiler warning. If `a.Amount` is f.e. a string you would get the exception since you cannot sum a string

Comment: The query works fine for me, if I select a field that is numeric. What type is .Amount?

Comment: I now have an error Error: Range variable 'Amount' hides a variable in an enclosing block or a range variable previously defined in the query expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asked another question with code and someone answered my question exactly so the answer is below:

```
  Dim totalPaid = db.Payments.Where(Function(a) a.ForJob = jobId).Sum(Function(a) a.Amount)
```

Comment: Hi, then maybe you should delete _this_ question. It only causes duplicates and clutter. Improving an existing question is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sum = (From a In db.Payments Where a.ForJob = id Select a.Amount).Sum();
```

Comment: I now have an error Error: Range variable 'Amount' hides a variable in an enclosing block or a range variable previously defined in the query expression.